# How to make website responsive to current screen aspect ratio?

Tags: html, responsive-design

As the title says how do you make a website responsive to the screens aspect ratio? So if it's 16:9 it'll look one way, but if it's 9:16 it'l look another way.

I've only tried setting a max/min width/height but I realized it wouldn't actually consider the aspect ratio just the screen size. So if a smartphone had a 1920px width it would look the same as a normal 1920p monitor, which would obviously be a problem.

Comment: completely wrong approach. You should not code for certain screen resolutions. First, there are too many different resolutions because of different panels and devices. Then, a browser will not always occupy the entire screen. Last but not least, the part where a website is displayed is not the height of the entire browser. You have to subtract the height of the browser menu, tabbar, and favorites...

Comment: As @tacoshy said, this is the wrong way of making things responsible, but if it HAS TO be done, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

Comment: The next thing you have to look into is the difference between CSS pixels (software pixels)  and physical pixels (hardware pixels). It is not the same for most mobile devices. Most mobile devices have a ratio of 1:2. which means,  that for every CSS pixel it consumes 2 hardware pixels and a 1920p Smartphone will behave the same as a 960p device.